# How to change edge attribute to vertex attribute on incident vertices

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, graph-theory

Is it possible to change a character edge attribute to a vertex attribute for the vertices that are incident on that edge?

Consider the following example:

```
data <- data.frame(neuron1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                    neuron2=c("G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"),
                    bridge=c("M","N","O","P","Q","R"))

g <- graph.data.frame(data, directed=FALSE)

summary(g)
IGRAPH UN-- 12 6 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), bridge (e/c)
```

I would like to assign the edge attribute 'bridge' to the vertex level, but I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Do your graphs always have the property that every node is in a doublet and that none of the doublets are connected?

Comment: So what's the desired output here?

Comment: @MrFlick Ideally, I would like to have a vertex attribute that holds the same information as in edge attribute `bridge`. Later I will use this new vertex attribute to color the vertices.

Comment: But what if there are conflicting bridges values?

Comment: @MrFlick if a vertex has more than one bridge, can a new vertex attribute called 'bridge2' be made?

Comment: Is that a question? This is why i want to know what the exact desired output for your sample input is. We can't program a solution if we don't know what it's supposed to do. But how you run into a problem where different verticies may have different numbers of attrbutes and which value should go in bridge, and which in bridge2, etc.

Comment: @MrFlick: The desired output is a graph that holds a number of vertex attributes that contain the information on the `bridge` edge attribute for which the vertex is incident upon (i.e. V(g)$bridge). If the vertex is incident upon multiple edges that have different 'bridge' values, a new vertex attribute (i.e. V(g)$bridge2) is made that records the information on that 'bridge' value. Does this answer your question? Thanks for taking the time and effort, once again, to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can simply do this by using the function below;

```
set_vertex_attr(graph, name, index = V(graph), value)
```

You can find it in the `igraph` dictionary:

http://igraph.org/r/doc/set_vertex_attr.html

Comment: Hi together, to the person who downvoted this. Could you please give me feedback on why you downvoted my answer? I would be really grateful for this and would like to know how to improve in the future. Thanks!